# Show two activities simultaneously

Tags: android, android-layout

I split my `LinearLayout` into two. Is there any possibility to show the other application on the layouts ? When I search with Google it's not possible. I need to know is there any possibility to show the other application view with my application.

Comment: Use `Fragments`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: I need to show my application UI and another application UI simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

no its not possible to displays 2 activities at the same time however,[fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) will do the job.

here is a good example for you:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possibility to show the other application view with my
>   application

Only one application can be shown at a time on the screen. It is possible to run multiple applications but **impossible to show multiple applications on the screen** at the same time.

However, you can create own application to show different functionalities/ widgets on one screen by using `Fragments`